# Unable to get a javascript/html searchbar to work

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine

I am unable to get my searchbar to return results, I am trying to get the search bar to take in keywords, upon submit it should search for the keywords in all the `<div>` in my site rather than a single page and display the matches in my searchresults.html page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('button-submit').onsubmit = function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:webflicks.co ' + document.getElementById('button-submit').value;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class = "search">
        <form id="searchbox" method="get" action="/search" autocomplete="off">
            <input name="q" type="text" size="15" placeholder="Enter keywords here..." />
            <input id="button-submit" type="submit" value=""/> 
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your submit event handler to the *form*, it won't fire on the button.

You'll also want to grab the value of the textbox and not the button.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('button-submit').onsubmit = function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:webflicks.co ' + document.getElementById('button-submit').value;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('button-submit').onsubmit = function() {
        window.location = "https://www.google.co.in/search?as_q="+ document.getElementById('button-submit').value +"&as_sitesearch=webflicks.co";            return false;
   }
    </script>
```

Hope this will help you..!!